# Is it possible to install SciPy with p7 python distribution?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

I am having a problem installing SciPy to a pre-built python distribution. The python distribution comes with a program called p7 (by DATADVANCE). The python version is 2.7.7 and the current numpy version is 1.7.1.

There is a NumPy already installed when it's downloaded but I also need SciPy to do what I want with the program.

I am trying to install using the setup.py script run using:

```
p7 --run setup.py build
```

This is effectively the same as:

```
python setup.py build
```

I have tried to install SciPy versions 0.11.0, 0.12.0 and 0.13.0 but I keep getting the same error:

```
    non-existing path in 'scipy/sparse/csgraph': '/home/Ben/DATADVANCE/pSeven-3.1/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include'
    non-existing path in 'scipy/sparse/csgraph': '/home/Ben/DATADVANCE/pSeven-3.1/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include'
    non-existing path in 'scipy/sparse/csgraph': '/home/Ben/DATADVANCE/pSeven-3.1/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include'
    non-existing path in 'scipy/sparse/csgraph': '/home/Ben/DATADVANCE/pSeven-3.1/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include'
    non-existing path in 'scipy/spatial': '/home/Ben/DATADVANCE/pSeven-3.1/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include'       
    non-existing path in 'scipy/spatial': '/home/Ben/DATADVANCE/pSeven-3.1/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include'       
    non-existing path in 'scipy/special': '/home/Ben/DATADVANCE/pSeven-3.1/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include'       
    non-existing path in 'scipy/special': '/home/Ben/DATADVANCE/pSeven-3.1/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include'       
    !!! [Interpreter] PkgNotFound: Could not find file(s) ['/home/Ben/DATADVANCE/pSeven-3.1/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/lib/npy-pkg-config/npymath.ini']
```

I have checked the directory and the folder "/home/Ben/DATADVANCE/pSeven-3.1/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/lib/npy-pkg-config/" doesn't exist at all.

I have also tried to install version 1.8.0 and 1.8.1 of NumPy using the setup.py script but I get this error message:

```
    non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'                      
    /bin/sh: svnversion: command not found                                  
    F2PY Version 2                                                          
    !!! [Interpreter] AttributeError: 'Configuration' object has no attribute 'add_define_macros'
```

In addition to this I have tried numpy 1.7.2 and it gets a little further but stops because it apparently needs python.h from the development version of python which isn't present.

I have tried to message the guys who maintain the program but they haven't got back to me yet.

Is there anything I can do to get SciPy to install?

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know modern version of pSeven contains quite recent version (0.14.0) of SciPy.
Here is the proofpic:

[image: pSeven 5.2 screenshot showing the version of SciPy embedded into it]

Comment: I haven't tried the most recent version, they seemed to have a version coming out every month at one point. Thanks for the information.